# SKLabelNode not appearing on actual device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, custom-font, sklabelnode

I am writing a spriteKit program in swift and want to have a score label in the corner of my screen, so that the user can monitor their points. I have the following code:

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
.
.
.
init(size:CGSize)
{
    super.init(size)
    scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"TechnoHideo")
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(200, 200)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}
```

I only included relevant code in this sample. So here is the weird part. This code works fine on the simulator, but the label does not show up on my actual iPad. The font is a custom font. I added its ttf file to the project, made sure it was in the build phases->copy bundle resources and made sure that it was under info->Fonts provided by application. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: I assume you read [Common custom font mistakes in iOS](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: I should also mention that my development partner tested the same code on his ipad and the same thing occured. The simulator worked, but the ipad did not.

Comment: Yes I read that article and mentioned that i did all the things listed in that article in the blurb under my code.

Comment: So I dont have this problem with an otf font, and with other ttf fonts the text appears in helvetica. Why is this font acting up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the font from a TTF to an OTF.

Comment: It works, it seems that the ttf fonts do not agree with modern technology :P